# Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened. Operating system error code 21(The device is not ready.)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened. Operating system error code 21(The device is not ready.).

Hi All,

I am a newbie to Image Upload in MS SQL Server using ASP.NET. its cool to upload a image in a query from the same machine as the server but when from a remote machine ASP.NET web application to MS SQL Server, I am getting the above mentioned error.

I don't understand what needs to be done, i have seen several threads and forums but i am not able to understand, can you please help me out on the same. I am looking for some descriptive steps to fix this issue.

```
Session["FileName"] equals some d drive file
```

**Query I use:**

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE user_info "
                                + "SET User_Image = (SELECT * FROM Openrowset(Bulk '" + Session["FileName"] + "', Single_Blob) AS User_Image) "
                                + "WHERE id =" + "22222";
```

- **I use SQL Authentication**
- **I have enabled both named pipes + TCP/IP**
- if **EXECUTE AS** is to be used, can someone explain the query. Is there any setting that need to be enabled. I am desperate :(

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, it would be good to show the actual values of `Session["FileName"]` when the command succeeds and fails. But assuming that it works when the file is on the local hard drive and fails when reading it from a mapped drive or UNC path, then you should have a look at [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835206/how-to-read-the-content-of-xml-file-in-the-remotenetwork-machine-through-mssql/12841980#12841980).

Comment: Hi Pondlife, the Session["Filename"] is a path of a file - something like D:/image.png. I saw the link you gave me - I cant ask every end user to do this.. :( - Is there any other way?

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to upload files from website users via `OPENROWSET()`? If so, that's completely the wrong approach: users should interact with the website only, not the database. Perhaps you're looking for the [`FileUpload` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx)?

Comment: Hey Pondlife, I have my user images stored in DB, when they want to change their image - they need to upload from Website, I use FileUpload to upload the image - then from there I try to use update query with openrowset to save the image in the TABLE. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old question, but it might help someone else in doubt.
To use bulk, file needs to be on the server.

This means you need to upload file from client machine to the server before using bulk.

Answer (score 0):

1) get the name of the  account sql server is running 
2) go to the folder in your Session["FileName"] equals some d drive file
3) give permissions on that folder to the sql server account  to read write permissions

Comment: Is there any other way? I cant ask every end user to do this.. :(

Comment: ok try  with xp_cmdshell first enable in your sql server , read the file name  and then update  in your procedure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: try these one EXEC master.sys.xp_subdirs
EXEC  xp_dirtree 
EXEC XP_cmdshell   try these one