# Xml Bulk Load Error Message 'Msg 4860'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I get the following error when trying to update an existing column of xml data type.  When I copy the file to the server and remote into the server and run the script it updates, but it will not let me run the script from my machine.  How can I run the command from my machine, or do I need to store the data in a place the server can access as well?

```
Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\Data\Data.xml" does not exist.
```

Comment: Of course, server should have the access to the xml file. In this case it is looking for a folder local to the server. Or use a network path.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835206/how-to-read-the-content-of-xml-file-in-the-remotenetwork-machine-through-mssql) might be relevant here, at least for the general points about paths and permissions

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question, I had it on a share on my machine.